# Cannot Sign In to enable iTunes & App Store within iOS Simulator

Tags: macos, xcode-simulator

In iPhone SE Simulator (iSO 10.3, running directly), I'm going to *Settings*, *Apple ID/iCloud* and trying to enable *iTunes & App Store* which is Off (I was manage already to log in to Apple ID).

[image: iPhone SE Simulator, Apple ID]

When enabling, I've got the confirmation message to *Set up iTunes and App Store*. After Continue I'm asked for the password.

When typed password and *Sign In*, I've got the following error:

> Could Not Sign In
>
> There was a problem connecting to the server.

[image: iPhone SE Simulator, Apple ID, Could Not Sign In, There was a problem connecting to the server]

Why this happens and how to fix that? Or it isn't possible to use App Store within iOS Simulator?

---

I've internet access inside Simulator and date/time is set correctly.

When checked the HTTPS traffic via `tcpdump`, it is happening both ways to `https://17.248.144.170/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In-app purchases would be the only reason you need to sign into iTunes/App Store since you cannot download apps from the App Store in the simulator.

According to [Technical Note TN2413](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html) you cannot test in-app purchases in the simulator.

> ## Cannot connect to iTunes Store
>
> The "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" issue may be due to one or more of the following reasons:
>
> - The sandbox may be unreachable.
> - Your app does not have a bundle version (CFBundleVersion). See Setting the Version Number and Build String for more information.
> - Your app is running in the Simulator, which does not support in-app purchase.
> - You are attempting to purchase a product that is unavailable for sale. See Query the App Store for product information before presenting your app’s store UI for more information.